# Nintex Workflow: Querying Another List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I'm currently working on a nintex list workflow for List A.  I want a certain step in this workflow to run when an associated folder for the item in library B is modified.

For example:
 User adds document to Item 1 in Library B
 This then fires Nintex step to change status of Item 1 in List A

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new workflow on Library B which updates a status column in List A when the document is added. In list A workflow you can use "wait for item update" shape to run you steps once the status was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list level workflow in library B, change the trigger settings from manual to Create or change item. Then configure it so that it queries for the item in List A using the common field(lookup field), Update the item.

Comment: The trigger can be changed in "Edit Workflow", "workflow settings", "start when items are created" and "start when items are modified. Sorry tried to add prints, wasn't sure how.